# how to select 100 rows by 100 rows from table?

Tags: node.js, psql, knex.js

I've a table that has 520 rows , I want to select the first 100 rows , then the next 100 rows , then third 100 rows , the the rest rows in the table , but i don't know how to do that with knexjs , I've tried to use `knex('table-name').select('*').where('id', '>',  10)`
but this is not accurate as ids is serialized so it's not consistent, so my point here is how to group the rows in any table to separate groups, no matter how number lies in this table , and i want to focus on how to select the rest rows that i mentioned above after selecting each group of 100 rows , i want the to select the rest rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`offset`](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-offset) and [`limit`](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-limit):

```
// First hundred rows
knex.select('*').from('table-name').limit(100).offset(0)
```

Comment: Mmh. I guess, you need to store some values somewhere within your application, like `count`, `limit` and `page`. `count` would be the total amount of rows in your table, `limit` the page size (let's say `100`) and `page` the actual page (initial value `0`). Then you do `knex.select('*').from('table-name').limit(limit).offset(page * limit); page++;` and so on. Hope you get the idea. If you are implementing a REST-API get these values via query parameters like `...?page=0&limit=100`. Or look for a library implementing a paginator.

Comment: thanks a lot , this helped me , i just put `offset('the last set i want to start from')` with out no limit and this selected the rest of the table , thank you